# Regex takes quite long when not matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text similar to the following:

```
rule "Example_Rule"
    dialect "java"
    no-loop true
    when
        $transaction : Transaction( someProperty1 == "123" )
    then
        $transaction.addReason( "SOME_MESSAGE" );
end
```

and I successfully process it using the below Regex:

```
const COLLECT_PATTERN = /[\s]*(Number|ArrayList)?\(?[ ]*(?:\$transaction[ ]*:[ ]*)?([^)]*)?\)?[ ]*(from accumulate|from collect)?[ ]*\(?[ ]*([aA-zZ0-9]*)[ ]*\([ ]*([^)]*)\)[ ]*(over window:length|over window:time)?[ ]*[(]?[ ]*([aA-zZ0-9 ]*)?[ ]*[)]?/;
const COLLECT_PATTERN_GLOBAL = /[\s]*(Number|ArrayList)?\(?[ ]*(?:\$transaction[ ]*:[ ]*)?([^)]*)?\)?[ ]*(from accumulate|from collect)?[ ]*\(?[ ]*([aA-zZ0-9]*)[ ]*\([ ]*([^)]*)\)[ ]*(over window:length|over window:time)?[ ]*[(]?[ ]*([aA-zZ0-9 ]*)?[ ]*[)]?/g;

const CONDITION_PATTERN = /([a-zA-Z0-9.$]*)[ ]*(==|!=|<=|>=|>|<|:|memberOf|not memberOf|before|after)[ ]*(\[[a-zA-Z0-9., $"]*]|[a-zA-Z0-9. $"]*)/;
const CONDITION_PATTERN_GLOBAL = /([a-zA-Z0-9.$]*)[ ]*(==|!=|<=|>=|>|<|:|memberOf|not memberOf|before|after)[ ]*(\[[a-zA-Z0-9., $"]*]|[a-zA-Z0-9. $"]*)/g;

const RULE_PATTERN = /([\s\S]*)(when)([\s\S]*)(then)([\s\S]*)(end)/;

try {

    var matches = myText.match(RULE_PATTERN);

    console.log(1);

    var whenList = matches[3].match(COLLECT_PATTERN_GLOBAL);

    console.log(2);

    whenList.forEach(function (when) {

        var whenParts = when.match(COLLECT_PATTERN);

        var conditions = [];
        var conditionList = whenParts[5] ? whenParts[5].match(CONDITION_PATTERN_GLOBAL) : null;
        var accumulateConditionList = whenParts[1] && whenParts[2] ? whenParts[2].match(CONDITION_PATTERN_GLOBAL) : null;

        var whenClass = $scope.classes.find(function (clazz) { return clazz.simpleName === whenParts[2]; });

        if (conditionList) conditions = conditions.concat(parseConditions(conditionList, whenClass)); 

    ...
    // some code accessing some nested part of whenList
    ...

} catch (exception) {
    console.log(exception);
}
```

and `parseConditions`:

```
var parseConditions = function (conditionList, whenClass, prefix) {

    var conditions = [];

    conditionList.forEach(function (condition) {

        var conditionParts = CONDITION_PATTERN.exec(condition);

        var value = conditionParts[3].trim(),
            operand = conditionParts[2].trim(),
            fieldItem = conditionParts[1].trim();

        var field = $scope.fields[whenClass.name].find(function (field) {
            return prefix ?
                field.name === prefix + '.' + fieldItem :
                field.name === fieldItem
        });

        ...
};
```

But if I change the text to the following:

```
rule "Example_Rule"
    dialect "java"
    no-loop true
    when
        $transaction : Transaction( someProperty2 memberOf [SomeProperty.VALUE_1, SomeProperty.VALUE_2] ) // Some line that I expect not to be matched
    then
        $transaction.addReason( "SOME_MESSAGE" );
end
```

I do not expect the text to be matched perfectly, but what happens is: I get `1` printed, but it takes forever for `2` to get printed. Right after, I get: `Property 'name' cannot be found on 'undefined'` for `'whenClass.name'`. What I think happening is that Regex on `var whenList = matches[3].match(COLLECT_PATTERN_GLOBAL);` gets into some sort of infinite loop/takes too long to match. Better example can be found on [github.com/hasancansaral/editor-demo](https://github.com/hasancansaral/editor-demo)

I do not expect it to match, but I need it to fail faster. How do I achieve this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In `RULE_PATTERN` you can gain by replacing every `*` with `*?`, making the "all" match lazy instead of greedy.

Comment: @trincot The effect will be the opposite if `when` appears closer to the string end. Swapping greediness does not account for better matching speed with arbitrary strings.

Comment: The `COLLECT_PATTERN_GLOBAL` is terrible, it won't work faster. It is slow because 
 - let alone the misfortunate `[aA-zZ0-9 ]` part that should be `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` - all its parts are *optional* ([except for](https://regex101.com/r/5zzSyM/1) a pair of `()`) and a lot can "fall into one another" because of that, and cause catastrophic backtracking. To solve this, you should provide the list of the pattern requirements, what it should match. Please edit the question with these details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main issue resides in this code. To fix this, place a conditional around this just as you did with the other lists you are creating.

This should not run if `whenParts[2]` === `null`:

```
var whenClass = $scope.classes.find(function (clazz) { 
    return clazz.simpleName === whenParts[2]; 
});
```

Explanation:

In the searched text causing this issue, sample 2, `whenParts[2]` is `null`. This results is the `find()` method searching through the entire list of classes. It ([`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)) eventually returns `undefined`.

(A bit of speculation here, but perhaps when `whenParts[2]` is not `null` a class name is found very quickly? Impossible to know from your question.)

So, `whenClass.name` doesn't exist on an `undefined`.

Additionally, the timing of the appearance or lack of `2` in the console is merely a result of the loop blocking the thread until it completes. *Rendering* in the console is asynchronous in most implementations and is often times produces false indications like this.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't help. I removed regex altogether and persisted what I needed to parse into the database.